# Timer continues after specified amount of time

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

i am trying to perform whats inside the while condition but when the condition ends the threads keep on going check the output i need to stop whats inside the while loop according to the timer basically doing the timer's job

```
 public static long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    public static long end = start + 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds * 1000 ms/sec  

   while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= end) {
                    Thread t = new Thread(new UserGenerator());
                    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Vote());
                    t.start();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    t1.start();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            System.err.println("Time Done");
```

output

```
Name:Alaine,Email:lg@shapirosher.com   ,SSN:516517   
Name:Adriana,Email:donbenchoff@comcast.net ,SSN:526527  
    Time Done
    User 516517   Voted
    User 526527   Voted
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)
```

Comment: Do you have some kind of `stop()` method in `UserGenerator` and `Vote` which you can call after the loop ?

Comment: @c0der no the thing is just keep adding thread.sleep not knowing the amount of time and how to calculate it

Comment: Not sure I follow, but if you can make a 'stop' method in `UserGenerator` that stops `UserGenerator` when called, it makes the solution easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the above code does:

- Executes for 10 seconds
- Spawns one thread of `UserGenerator` and one thread of `Vote` per second
- Goes into sleep state in between

So, after 10 seconds, `while` loop will end and `main` thread will exit. However, 5 `threds` started by it will continue to run (until their `run` method finishes or an exception is thrown). It depends on how `run` method is implemented in `UserGenerator` and `Vote` classes. E.g. if there's an infinite loop, those threads will continue to run and the program will never exit.

Comment: so for this timer to work there should be a condition added to the run() for both Usergenerator() and vote saying that if (System.currentTimeMillis() <= end) then execute else thread.stop()?

Comment: Yes, that or any other termination condition.

Comment: `thread.stop()` is deprecated. Don't stop the thread but stop what running in it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have enough information for a full answer, however you can try this:

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = start + (10 * 1000); // 10 seconds * 1000 ms/sec

    List<UserGenerator> us = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Vote> vs = new ArrayList<>();

    Thread  t, t1; 
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= end) {
        UserGenerator u; Vote v;

        t = new Thread( u = new UserGenerator());
        t1 = new Thread(v = new Vote());
        t.start();
        us.add(u);

        if(end - System.currentTimeMillis() >= 1000)
                            Thread.sleep(1000);

        t1.start();
        vs.add(v);

        if(end - System.currentTimeMillis() >= 1000)
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    t.interrupt(); t1.interrupt();

    //the following may be redundant. It depends in what
    // UserGenerator and Vote do 
    for(int i =0; i < us.ssize() ; i++) {
        us.get(i).stop();
        vs.get(i).stop();
    }

    System.err.println("Time Done");
}
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = start + (10 * 1000); // 10 seconds * 1000 ms/sec

    List<UserGenerator> us = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Vote> vs = new ArrayList<>();

    Thread  t, t1; 
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= end) {
        UserGenerator u; Vote v;

        t = new Thread( u = new UserGenerator());
        t1 = new Thread(v = new Vote());
        t.start();
        us.add(u);

        if(end - System.currentTimeMillis() >= 1000)
                            Thread.sleep(1000);

        t1.start();
        vs.add(v);

        if(end - System.currentTimeMillis() >= 1000)
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    t.interrupt(); t1.interrupt();

    //the following may be redundant. It depends in what
    // UserGenerator and Vote do 
    for(int i =0; i < us.ssize() ; i++) {
        us.get(i).stop();
        vs.get(i).stop();
    }

    System.err.println("Time Done");
}
```

Comment: what will the stop function contain ? since my run() looks like this     @Override
    public void run() {
            try {
                engine.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(new UserRegisterEvent(u));
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UserGenerator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

Comment: the stop function should stop the thread from reaching the run function isnt that right ?